# What does "variable or 0" mean in python?

Tags: python, variables

What is the meaning of the following statement in python:

```
x = variable_1 or 0
```

`variable_1` is an object. What value does `x` have above? And what is the type of `x`?

Comment: try   None, 1, 0, "", [], {} ....     sometimes, (a and b or c) can ben used as (a?b:c) in c-lang .

Comment: @fanlix But only sometimes. `b if a else c` is better, as `a and b or c` evaluates to `c` if `b` is false.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If `variable_1`  evaluates to `False` , x is set to `0`, otherwise to `variable_1`

Think of it as

```
if variable_1:
  x = variable_1
else:
  x = 0
```

Comment: Not just to `None` or `False` - to anything falsey.

Comment: To be even more correct: If `variable_1` is `None` or `False` or `0`,  if `__len__` exists on that object and returns `0`, of if `non_zero` exists on that object and return `0` or `False`. Hope I didn't forget something.

Comment: Its actually `__nonzero__` ;-) Or, in Python 3, the much easier to spell `__bool__`.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Just say "if `variable_1` is false" or "is a false expression" or such.

Answer (score 22):

`x` will be `0` if `variable_1` evaluates as false, otherwise it will be `variable_1`

```
>>> 'abc' or 0
'abc'
>>> '' or 0
0
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'] or 0
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [] or 0
0
```

Comment: More semantically, you can see this pattern a lot in Python/Perl/Ruby as `setting = user_specified_option or default`.

Answer (score 4):

`x` will be initialized to `variable_1` if its value is not `None` or `False`

simple exemple :

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = 2
>>> a or 0
0
>>> b or 0
2
```

Comment: a little nitpicking: if `variable_1` is `[]`, then `x` will become `0`, because even `variable_1` is neither `None` nor `False`, it will *evaluate* to `False`

Comment: absolutely, I forgot to mention it. jamylak's answer is better

Answer (score 2):

```
x = variable_1 or 0
```

It means that if `variable_1` evaluates to `False` (i.e. it is considered "empty" - see documentation for magic method `__nonzero__`), then `0` is assigned to `x`.

```
>>> variable_1 = 'foo'
>>> variable_1 or 0
'foo'
>>> variable_1 = ''
>>> variable_1 or 0
0
```

It is equivalent to "if variable_1 is set to anything non-empty, then use its value, otherwise use 0".

Type of `x` is either type of `variable_1` or `int` (because 0 is `int`).

Comment: Falsey things aren't necessarily "empty" things, even though all the builtin sequence and mapping types are falsey if and only if they're empty. eg, `False` and `0` are both falsey, but calling numeric types "empty" doesn't make a great deal of sense.