# Trying to understand a simple feature about 'and' command in python. Can anyone clarify it?

Tags: python

In Python, if I write

```
z = 1 and 2
print z
```

Then it yields "2".

But if I write

```
z = 0 and 2
print z
```

Now, it yields "0".

It may not be much important in real life problem, but I'm trying to understand the logic here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213430/what-does-variable-or-0-mean-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0`, `[]`, `""` are all *false-ish* (they are treated as `False` in a python condition). `and` returns the first *false-ish* value or the last one. This is called [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). That's why in one case it returns `2` (the last) and in the other it returns `0` (the *false-ish*).

In fact if you think about the logic operation, you can short-circuit this behaviour:

```
x and y (with x false-ish) -> x  
x and y (with x true-ish)  -> y
```

When plugged into a condition it will evaluate as:

- In the first case it evaluates the boolean result of `x` which is `False`. This is the correct result for the `and` operation, since `False and y` = `False` for any `y`.
- In the second case it evaluates the boolean value of `y`. Since `x` is True, the result of `and` should be `False` when `y` is `False` and `True` when `y` is `True` (it reflects the value of `y`).

Answer (score 2):

```
c = a and b
```

is the same as

```
if a:
    c=b
else:
    c=a
```

I think more interesting is `or`:

```
c = a or b
```

is the same as

```
if a:
    c=a
else:
    c=b
```

Note also that `if a:` is a short way of `if bool(a):`. `bool` returns `False` for this objects/values:

```
None, 0, False, "", [], tuple(), dict(), set()
```

As  you can see, they are all somehow empty...

Comment: Thanks for your kind clarification. You also provided with the difference of 'or' and 'and' feature. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `and` operator in python short circuits. That is: it only evaluates enough operands (from left to right) as are necessary to determine whether the outcome is True or False.  The result of `and` is False so in the second case, where 0 evaluates to False, and returns 0, but as 1 is True, the second operand must also be evaluated and returned.

Answer (score 1):

0 is treated as False and anything above zero is treated as True so z = 1 and 2 sets z equal to 2 and z = 0 and 2 is 0 because it evaluates to False.